# Wrap TypeScript's inferred data type with a generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a class - let's call it `DataRepository` - that has a bunch of methods in it which fetch data and do operations.

I have defined a generic `Result` type in my code:

```
export type Result<T, E = Error> =
  | { ok: true; value: T }
  | { ok: false; error: E };
```

Now, given a method something like this:

```
async getSomeData() {
   const data = await this.prisma.dataset.findMany({ ... })
   
   if (!data) {
      return {
          ok: false,
          error: new Error("Invalid ...")
      }
   }

   return {
      ok: true,
      value: data
   }
}
```

TypeScript is smart enough to infer and realize that the function returns something like this:

```
Promise<{
    ok: boolean;
    error: Error;
    value?: undefined;
} | {
    ok: boolean;
    value: ...[]; // removed for brevity
    error?: undefined;
}>
```

When I call this function elsewhere though, it doesn't realize that the type union is discriminated. That is, if `ok` is `true` then `value` must always be there, and that if `ok` is `false` then `error` must always be there

For example,

```
const repo = new DataRepository(...)
const data = repo.getSomeData()

if (!result.ok) throw result.error // <--- this gives me issues
```

```
Expected an error object to be thrown. `result.error` may be `undefined`.
```

This is what the `Result` type solves

I can fix it by adding a return type to `getSomeData()` - something like:

```
async function getSomeData(): Promise<Result<MyDataType, Error>> { ....}
```

But this requires me to define another type - `MyDataType` - manually in my code which I need to make changes to every time I change the DB Queries to get the benefit of types.

Coming to my question, then, is there a way I can wrap this function in the `Result` generic without defining the generic `T` type and let TypeScript infer that automatically from the function while realizing that it is a discriminated union return type?

Reproducible Example: https://tsplay.dev/Wvy4rm

Also as code:

```
export type Result<T, E = Error> =
    | { ok: true; value: T }
    | { ok: false; error: E };

class DataRepository {
    async getSomeData() {
        const data = await Promise.resolve(
            Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : { something: 42 }
        );

        if (!data) {
            return {
                ok: false,
                error: new Error("Invalid ..."),
            };
        }

        return {
            ok: true,
            value: data,
        };
    }
}

async function example() {
    const repo = new DataRepository();
    const result = await repo.getSomeData();

    if (!result.ok) throw result.error; // this works without stricter ESLint rules around throwing only errors

    // Now we can do something with `result.value`
    const something = result.value.something // <-- this complains about `result.value` possibly being undefined
}
```

Comment: Sorry about not having the example. Yours is a pretty close representation. I've extended it slightly to expand how the same problem affects `result.value` as well - here you go: 
https://tsplay.dev/Wvy4rm

Comment: Yup! Added link + full reproducible code in OP

Comment: Just as a side note: In general, it's best to let errors be errors (promise rejections in this case) rather than converting them to successes (fulfillments) with an error code.

Comment: it's an attempt to have something similar to Rust's `Result` type in TS but with some infer magic. i understand the try...catch and throw paradigm but the code is currently structured like this in this project and is riddled with a ton of types that need to change everytime DB queries change

Comment: Yeah, legacy stuff. Always fun. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with an approach *(surely not a novel one)* that handles the inference *inside* the `getSomeData` method, while at the same time reducing boilerplate (assuming there are other methods like `getSomeData`). It uses a utility function like this:

```
function makeResult<T>(value: T, errorString: string): Result<Exclude<T, null>, Error> {
    if (value) {
        return {
            ok: false,
            error: new Error(errorString),
        };
    }
    return {
        ok: true,
        value: value as Exclude<T, null>,
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a generic function that accepts the type of `data` which can include `null`, but produces a `Result` where the `value` type does not include `null`.

Here's how you use it in `DataRepository`:

```
class DataRepository {
    async getSomeData() {
        const data = await Promise.resolve(
            Math.random() < 0.5 ? null : { something: 42 }
        );

        return makeResult(data, "Invalid ...");
    }
}
```

The inferred return type of `getSomeData` above is `Result<{something: number}, Error>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KMgA)

That particular `makeResult` assumes you want to just use `Error` in the error case, but you could create one that lets you be more specific with what `E` is in `Result` by expanding on the concept.

Comment: Ooh this is pretty good. Thank you for this!